# validation and submission of form in laravel5 does not work

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I have AuthController

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use ConnectIn\Http\Requests;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getSignUp()
    {
        return view('auth.signup');
    }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|max:255',
            'useremail' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
            'userpassword' => 'required|min:8'
            ]);
        //dd("all OK");
    }
}
```

and my routes are

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignup',
    'as' => 'auth.signup',
    ]);

Route::post('/', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignUp',    
    ]);
```

signup.blade.php is

```
@extends ('templates.default')    

@section('register')

<div id="login-page" class="row">

      <form class="login-form" method="post" action="{{route('auth.signup')}}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 center">
            <h4>Register</h4>
            <p class="center">Join to our community now !</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
            <label for="username" class="center-align">Username</label>
            @if($errors->has('username')) 
              <div class="error">{{$errors->first('username')}}</div>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-communication-email prefix"></i>
            <input id="email" name="useremail" type="email">
            <label for="email" class="center-align">Email</label>
             @if($errors->has('email')) 
              <div class="error">{{$errors->first('email')}}</div>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="password" name="userpassword" type="password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            @if($errors->has('userpassword')) 
              <div class="error">{{$errors->first('userpassword')}}</div>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="password-again" type="password">
            <label for="password-again">Password again</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="submit" value="Regiter Now" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12"/>            
          </div>          
        </div>
      </form>

  </div>    

@stop
```

at this point I'm not getting any errors but not able to submit the form and my validation does not work at all, am I missing something there please.

Comment: Can you try `url('/')` as the form action?

Answer (score 0):

In the `postSignUp` function, change your code to:

```
$this->validate($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'useremail' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        'userpassword' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);
```